# Куски замерзшего льда - плеоназм?

Tags: грамотная-речь, литература, стилистическая-сочетаемость

Зачастую услышишь: .  "Куски замерзшего льда,  замороженная глыба льда и т. д."  Лёд - замерзшая либо замороженная субстанция по факту,  так стоит ли давать ему дополнительное определение? И, если глыбу мы уже определили, как лёд,  стоит ли добавлять причастие "замороженная"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лёд — вода в **твёрдом** агрегатном состоянии. Льдом иногда называют некоторые вещества в твёрдом агрегатном состоянии, которым свойственно иметь жидкую или газообразную форму при комнатной температуре; в частности, сухой лёд, аммиачный лёд или метановый лёд.

**Процесс перехода из жидкого состояния в твердое, то есть получение льда из воды, условно называют замерзанием льда.**

Выражение ***замерзший лед*** является плеоназмом, но в таком значении  (как результат) оно обычно не применяется.

Однако замерзание льда **как процесс** можно встретить в речи.

Например:

***Лед на реке замерз идеально. Идеально замерзший лед.***

Как сказать по-другому?  Лед на реке образовался идеально?

Вот мы и говорим:

*Как быстро заморозить (= получить) лед в кубиках.*

*Если лёд начнёт замерзать с середины, то его может раздавить давление реки.*

И т.д.

Comment: Сказать можно так: "На реке ровный лёд, прочный лёд, идеальный лёд, река замерла, скованная идеально ровным льдом," - " замёрз" - лишнее пустое слово здесь, что и определяет его, как плеоназм. А когда "лёд намерзает с середины" , это уже не плеоназм, - без глагола не обойтись в данном случае. Зато можно заменить: образуется, наростает, становится. В науке свои законы правописание. Там важна не красивая правильная речь, а чёткая и ясная передача информации.  Но ответ хороший,  спасибо вам за него!

Answer (score 3):

*Лёд — замерзшая либо замороженная субстанция по факту...*
Совершенно верно, только это — "голая" физическая формулировка.

*...так стоит ли давать ему дополнительное определение?*
Конечно, стоит.

Лед по своему состоянию и нашему с вами восприятию бывает разный: замерзший, колотый, ноздреватый, талый и растаявший (это уже, собственно, вода), плавучий (мы и так знаем, что он легче воды), сплошной, предательский, коварный, черный (на асфальте), голый...

Сравните разные определения:
1. **Шуга́** — рыхлые скопления твёрдой фазы агрегатного состояния вещества, в нормальных условиях имеющего жидкое состояние.
2. **Шуга́** — мелкий **рыхлый** лёд, появляющийся перед ледоставом или во время ледохода.

Если лед может быть *рыхлым*, то что же ему мешает быть *замерзшим*?

*Лед-то получается, но бутылки уже не оказывается: она раскалывается под напором **замерзающего льда*** (Я. Перельман. Физика на каждом шагу).

*Оно образовалось в результате тысячелетнего воздействия стихий на **замерзающий, тающий и снова замерзающий лед*** (Х. Сайдз. Царство льда).

***Молодой, только-только замерзший лед*** на полынье с западной стороны был еще слишком тонок, чтобы выдержать нарты, но вполне мог справиться с весом одного эскимоса (Р. Пири. По большому льду. Северный полюс).

**Дополнение**

1. **Куски замерзшего** (пористого, тающего, рыхлого) **льда** — здесь при помощи определений упор делается не на процесс превращения воды в лёд, а на фактуру, "качество", состояние льда.
2. Торосы — это довольно редкое явление в Финском заливе, но красивое и мощное необыкновенно.

Представьте себе зимний шторм: волны несут и громадные льдины, которые наползают друг на друга, и острые ледяные обломки, и тонны мокрого комкующегося снега. Вода со временем спадает, а на берегу и мелководье остаются многометровые нагромождения.
Влажный морской ветер на морозе превращает некоторые ледово-снежные кучи именно в **замороженные глыбы льда** (иногда они "доживают" до апреля).
Весной же структура глыбного льда меняется: он крошится и разваливается (мы говорим — *становится тухлым*). Это теперь уже никакие не глыбы, а обыкновенные грязные (от песка) груды тающего льда.

Думаю, что в этих случаях плеоназма нет.

Comment: Итог какой? - Не плеоназм?